# How to get a list of ASP.NET events which fired till a breakpoint?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, profiling, intellitrace

How do I get a list of ASP.NET events which fired till a breakpoint was hit? For example, if I put a breakpoint in Page_Load, I want to see events like preinit, init, LoadViewState, loadpostdata..etc were fired. I was looking at IntelliTrace but this kind of information wasn't there.

Any tool provides this information? A Profiler? A commercial product is fine.

I am using a few third party server controls and such a tool would help a lot in debugging.

Comment: Do you have subscribed to this events? If you, you might use a profiler (like ANTS, which I'm using @work). If not, they probably won't show up in a profiler.

Comment: What do you mean subscribe to events? Subscribe to preinit event?

Comment: Do you have an event handler for all the events you want to track?

Comment: No. I want to see every event even if I don't have my own override or handler.

Answer (score 0):

You may checkout the [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class.

Comment: Does the stacktrace shows events / event handler that are already done, and are not part of the call hierarchy for the current line?